# Append a dict to an array within loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible

How do you append a dict to an array from within a '''with_items''' loop?

```
  - set_fact:
      my_dict:
        name:  "{{ (item.content|from_json).name.0.value }}"
        id:    "{{ (item.content|from_json).nid.0.value }}"
        email: "{{ (item.content|from_json).mail.0.value }}"
      effort_members: "{{ effort_members }} + [ {{ my_dict }} ]"
    with_items: "{{ members_obj.results }}"
```

The above DOES NOT work but it is a good representation of what I would like to accomplish.  If I define the dict ahead of time this append works fine but it is appending the same dict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mistakes:

- you are missing the `default` filter for the first iteration
- you define `my_dict` unnecessarily for each iteration - use a helper variable instead
- your template is badly broken, it creates a string with `+` inside instead of concatenating lists

Fixed code:

```
- with_items: "{{ members_obj.results }}"
  set_fact:
    effort_members: "{{ effort_members|default([]) + [ my_dict ] }}"
  vars:
    my_dict:
      name:  "{{ (item.content|from_json).name.0.value }}"
      id:    "{{ (item.content|from_json).nid.0.value }}"
      email: "{{ (item.content|from_json).mail.0.value }}"
```

Comment: Works like a charm.   I'm gonna need to read more on the filters.   MTTR 17 min, fantastic.